# How to execute the app just by root or specific user?

Tags: permissions

I wanna install an application to linux and it's important it just execute by the specific user or root.
for example openssl, As you know when the users, enter the command like this :

```
openssl version
```

they can see the version of openssl and they notify that, the openssl installed in my system, so the questions are :

1. How can I avoid the users to figure it out, which apps installed on my system and how avoid them to execute that?or looking for that with commands like `grep`, `find`, `which` , `whereis`
2. How can I say, a specific app(like `openssl`) only can execute by user01 not anyone else, and even they don't notify this app installed at all ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily what you can do, just play with permissions:

Create a group for all users allowed to use the application, let's say `sslusers`.

```
 sudo groupadd sslusers
```

Find the terminal program (use which), for example, openssl. Change its ownership accordingly :

```
sudo chown root:sslusers /usr/bin/openssl
```

Allow execution for the owner, and the group. Deny for others :

```
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/openssl
```

now let's make a test :

```
$ openssl

bash: /usr/bin/openssl: Permission denied

$ openssl -v

bash: /usr/bin/openssl: Permission denied


$ openssl version

bash: /usr/bin/openssl: Permission denied
```

Comment: thank you so much , in this case the users seeing the Permission denied which means there is openssl but they don't have access to that how can we say for example -bash: openssl: command not found

Comment: Move the binaries from the default PATH

Comment: like this ./configure --prefix=[mypath] ?

Comment: Yes, this for apps compiled from source code then you can install to some path out of  those found in $PATH. But you then have to call the binary using the full path such as `/opt/some/dir/some/app`

Comment: ./configure --prefix=[/opt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25190/discussion-between-maythux-and-sam).